# nginx redirect based on domain and amend the url

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

i have several server names as in www.example.com example.com www.example.de example.de. If there is no arguments I would like to amend the language to the URL 
for example

www.example.com ---> www.example.com?language=en

example.de ---> example.de?language=de

regrads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for the absence of arguments by comparing `$args` with an empty string. For example:

```
if ($args = "") { 
    return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri?language=en; 
}
```

If you have your domains implemented within different `server` blocks, you can customise the `return` statement appropriately.

If you need to implement all of this within a single `server` block supporting multiple host names, you may need to use a `map` directive to calculate the value of the language parameter. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more.

This is not a perfect solution, as the edge condition `www.example.com?` will result in `www.example.com??language=en` which does not look nice.